# Kaminari wrong url in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, pagination, kaminari

I've found similar questions about Kaminari, however none of the answers worked on my machine.

Basically, when I'm paginating, the number of pages is correct, but the URL I'm redirected to is wrong.
This one below is the action in my controller

```
def index_offered

  @machines = Machine.not_sponsored.offered.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(5)

end
```

Now, when I implement Kaminari in the view

```
<%= paginate @machines%>
```

I obtain 3 pages (correct) of pagination, the links are:

```
0.0.0.0:3000/?page=2
0.0.0.0:3000/?page=3
```

While they should be

```
0.0.0.0:3000/offered-machinery?page=2
0.0.0.0:3000/offered-machinery?page=3
```

Could the catch be nested in the routing? Here it is the route that regards the index_offered action

```
  match 'offered-machinery' => 'machines#index_offered', :as => :offered_machinery
```

I've also tried to pass params in the view by typing

```
<%= paginate @machines , :params => {:controller => "Machines" , :action => 'index_offered'}%>
```

and uncommented the line in routes.rb:

```
   match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

but in that case, I obtain these URLs instead:

```
0.0.0.0:3000/Machines/offered-machinery?page=2
0.0.0.0:3000/Machines/offered-machinery?page=3
```

How could I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change de controller name to "machines":

{:controller => "machines" , :action => 'index_offered'}%>